# New to Probability. I'm not sure if I answer this problem right?

Tags: probability

I'm not sure if I answer this question correctly, thank you for your help in adavance.

On any given day, the probability that a printing machine is not working is 0.1. If the machine is working, then a daily profit of 1000 is made. if the machine is not working, than a loss of 100 occurs. let the random variable W denote the daily profit/loss. a)what is the support W? b)what is the expected daily profit (what is E[W])?

This is my answer:

W ∈ {1000, -100}

W = X

P(X = 0.1) = -100 P(X = .9) = 1000 E[W] = E[X] = Σg(x)f(x) = Σxf(x)

Therefore (0.1)(-100)+(0.9)(1000) = 890

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for a speedy response.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  I wouldn't say perfectly fine.  The bit in the middle is a bit of a muddle.

Comment: There is no reason to introduce $X$. They gave you $W$ for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> W ∈ {1000, -100}
>
> W = X

What is X?

> P(X = 0.1) = -100 P(X = .9) = 1000 E[W] = E[X] = Σg(x)f(x) = Σxf(x)

No.   It is: $~\mathsf P(W {=} {-100}) = 0.1~,~ \mathsf P(W{=}1000)=0.9~,~ \mathsf E(W) = \sum_{w\in\{-100,1000\}} w \mathsf P(W{=}w)$

Reality Check: A probability measure must equal a number between $0$ and $1$.

> Therefore (0.1)(-100)+(0.9)(1000) = 890

Yes, though you had the factors mixed up, the error cancelled.

$\mathsf E(W)$ $ = (-100)\mathsf P(W{=}{-100})+(1000)\mathsf P(W{=}1000) \\ = (-100)(0.1)+(1000)(0.9) \\ = 890$

Comment: It makes sense, "Reality Check: A probability measure must equal a number between 00 and 11." I thought W ∈ {1000, -100} was the support becuase of this statement in the question,  "let the random variable W denote the daily profit/loss". I had it a lil mixed up, thank you for the clarification.